# Synchronized method isn't working as i expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Hi i just learned about multi threading and how synchronized works in java so i tried to test it out.
so I have this class:

```
public class testMulti extends Thread{
 manageThread obj; //has 2 fields, boolean flag and task name

 testMulti(manageThread obj){
   this.obj = obj;
}

  public void run() {
     switch(obj.taskName) { 
        case "x" : 
          while(true){
            enterQ();
            obj.doX() // print "x" and sleep for 5 secs
            obj.iBusy = false;
          } 

         case "y" : 
           while(true){
             enterQ();
             obj.doX() // print "y" and sleep for 5 secs
             obj.iBusy = false;
           } 

        case "z" : 
          while(true){
            enterQ();
            obj.doX() // print "z" and sleep for 5 secs
            obj.iBusy = false;
         } 
     }
  }

synchronized public void enterQ(){
   while(true) {
         if(!obj.iBusy) {
          obj.iBusy = true;
          return;
         }
     }
 }  
}
```

I also have this separate main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  manageThread obj = new manageThread();
  obj.taskName = "x";
  testMulti test1 = new testMulti(obj);
  test2.start();
  obj.taskName = "y";
  testMulti test2 = new testMulti(obj);
  test2.start();
  obj.taskName = "z";
  testMulti test3 = new testMulti(obj);
  test3.start();
}
```

i have 5 secs delay after "x" being printed but "y" and "z" appear in the same time and i dunno why. if synchronized allow just 1 thread at a time so isn't z suppose to be stuck in `enterQ()` until y finish?

Comment: The `testMulti.enterQ()` method is synchronized on the current instance, and you have three separate instances.

Comment: I doubt it is the output. Please paste your exact code. In your main function you are changing task name for the same object, so it would print the same letter multiple times

Comment: @Rumd Unless he has declared `manageThread.obj` as `transient` this output is what you would expect.

Comment: FWIW: It looks as if you're using `iBusy` to create your own locking mechanism, but `synchronized` _is_ a locking mechanism...

Comment: Also, It looks as if your `run()` method only does one thing, and it keeps the lock locked for the entire time. That is, you are trying to make three threads that each do their thing one-at-a-time. That defeats the whole purpose of threading, which is to allow different threads to each do their thing at the _same_ time.

Answer (score 1):

As @user207421 mentions in his comment you are using three separate instances of the `testMulti` class and thus synchronizing on three different locks. See [*synchronized Methods*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) in the JLS:

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class
>   object for the method's class is used.

The simplest (but not entirely correct fix) would be to synchronize on `testMulti.obj`instead of the `enterQ` method:

```
public void enterQ(){
    synchronized(obj) {
        while(true) {
            if(!obj.iBusy) {
                obj.iBusy = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

This is not entirely correct since `obj.iBusy = false` is called from a non synchronized context, which doesn't guarantee that the change is seen by other threads. See the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1) for all the gory details.